# How to refactor Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a query that retrieves data from 5 tables using joins. While I obtain the right result, it's quite slow.

The tables:

- data_bundles
- vendors
- ussd_strings
- products users
- data_bundles_category

How can I refactor this?

Also, the setup does not use models.

```
$data_bundle_transaction = DB::table('data_bundles')
    ->select('*','data_bundles.phone_number as data_bundles_phone_number')
    ->join('vendors','vendors.vendor_id','=','data_bundles.vendor_id')
    ->join('ussd_strings','data_bundles.product_id','=','ussd_strings.product_id')
    ->join('products','data_bundles.product_id','=','products.product_id')
    ->join('users','users.user_id','=','data_bundles.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('data_bundle_category', 'data_bundle_category.product_id', '=', 'data_bundles.product_id')
    ->where('data_bundles.status',0)
    ->where('data_bundles.network','like',  '%' . $request->network.'%')
    ->where('data_bundle_category.data_category', '=', $request->type)->first();
```

Comment: What refactor do you want to do? Please share what you want to achieve.

Comment: Currently, the query takes a long time to complete. I need one that improves the speed.

Comment: Please check if the columns on where clauses, has index. Columns like status,  network and data_category from data_bundles table.

Comment: There are no indexes on these columns

Comment: Please sow us the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each relevant table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using joins with multiple conditions, this way you will join less data and query will be faster

```
$data_bundle_transaction = DB::table('data_bundles')
->select('*','data_bundles.phone_number as data_bundles_phone_number')
->join('vendors','vendors.vendor_id','=','data_bundles.vendor_id')
->join('ussd_strings','data_bundles.product_id','=','ussd_strings.product_id')
->join('products','data_bundles.product_id','=','products.product_id')
->join('users','users.user_id','=','data_bundles.user_id')
->leftJoin('data_bundle_category', function() use ($request){
    $join->on('data_bundle_category.product_id', '=', 'data_bundles.product_id');
    $join->on('data_bundle_category.data_category', '=', $request->type);
})
->where('data_bundles.status',0)
->where('data_bundles.network','like',  '%' . $request->network.'%')
->first();
```